# VBScript Instr function always return 0

Tags: vbscript

I have an application wrote by classic ASP. I need to compare if string1 contains string2 so I use instr function. However, even the string1 contains string2, it always returns 0. Where is the problem of my code?

```
function Findstring(string1,string2)
    dim findstr,loc

    on error resume next
    loc= instr(1,Lcase(string1),Lcase(string2),1)
    if loc>0  then
        findstr=true

    else
        findstr= false

    end if


  end function
```

Comment: I guess you have messed up on the order of parameters: `InStr(1, Lcase(string2), Lcase(string1), 1)` will give the desired result. 1st string param is the *string to be searched*, 2nd is the *string to search for*. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c(v=vs.84).aspx) ... *To be honest, I had to re-read the documentation myself before I could explain this.*

Comment: Not sure if this is a copy/paste error, but your function does not return anything.

Comment: string1: The string to be searched. string2:The string expression to search for. for example: string1 is "I am a student", string2 is "am"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function FindString( string1, string2 )
    FindString = False 
    On Error Resume Next
    FindString = CBool( InStr(1, LCase(string1), LCase(string2), 1) > 0 )
End Function
```

This function will return `True` if `string2` is contained inside `string1` and `False` in any other case.

**note**: Why the `CBool` if the comparision operator `>` already generates a boolean? Because we can call the function passing a `Null` value. If any of the strings being compared is `Null`, the `InStr` function returns `Null` and the test `Null > 0` evaluates to `Null`. But `CBool( Null )` will generate an error, captured by the previous `On Error` (that will also handle problems with objects)